# Two folded polymorphism is weird, how to make it extensible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, virtual-functions

For example, I have an abstract base class `A` and `B`. `A` has a virtual method as follows

```
class A
{
public:
    virutal void f(B& b) = 0;
};
```

For class A1

```
class A1 : public A
{
public:
    void f(B& b) override { b.f(A1); }
};
```

And thus for `B`, it needs a virtual method `f(A1)`

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void f(A1& a) = 0;
};
```

And in `class B1 : public B`, the virtual method is implemented. The problem is that when another `class A2 : public A` is added, I have to add a virtual method `virtual void f(A2& a) = 0` in class `B`, which I think it breaks the code because I don't know if `A2` even `A1` is added or not when I design class `B`. How to avoid it but implement the equivalent requirements? Any C++ feature can be used even with templates.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as a virtual template function in C++ (this is what I believe you're trying to accomplish, after parsing your question).

The closest, and the least ugly solution I can think of, is to have the virtual function in base class `B` take the base class `A` as a parameter:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void f(A& a) = 0;
};
```

`B1` overrides that, and then uses `dynamic_cast` to cast its parameter to an instance of `A1`.

In this manner, you can continue an define each `Ax` and `Bx` pair of derived classes, without having to change the API interface in the base class, between the two hierarchies.

A bit ugly, but the question states "any C++ feature can be used", and `dynamic_cast` certainly qualifies under that requirement.